# How to write a json to add a list?

Tags: java, json

I need to create a json like this.

```
{
    "List": [
        {
            "Description": "ABC",
            "Id": "music",
            "Issent": "0"
        },
        {
            "Description": "ABC",
            "Id": "music",
            "Issent": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is the code which i'm using to write the json. But it does not display all the values which i'm getting through the database.It repeats the data from the last column of the database

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();

try {
    Statement ac = DBL.getConnection().createStatement();
    ResultSet r5 = ac.executeQuery("Select * from msg");
    while (r5.next()) {
        System.out.println("Value taken from database" + r5.getString("content"));

        data.put("Description", r5.getString("content"));
        data.put("Id", r5.getString("id"));
        data.put("Issent",r5.getString("issent"));

        ja.put(jo);    
    }
    ja.put(data);

    System.out.println(data);

    JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();

    ret = mainObj.put("List", ja).toString();
}
```

Comment: Provided `JSON` is incorrect. `}` should be at last position. Also second `JSON` in `List` should also be in `{}`

Comment: Problem is not with the json. Ineed to write a json like this.

Comment: the problem is with the `JSON` , if the `JSON  ` itself is incorrect how will you be able to parse/create it.

Comment: Yes I know.This is a hand written json code. Sorry I have missed at the end. I need to create a json. But there is a problem in my java code.

Comment: @user3079570 although it is just an example you should make it correct.

Comment: Ok i have adjusted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    JSONObject final = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
try {
    Statement ac = DBL.getConnection().createStatement();
    ResultSet r5 = ac.executeQuery("Select * from msg");
   while(r5.next()){
        System.out.println("Value taken from database"+r5.getString("content"));
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("Description", r5.getString("content"));
        jo.put("Id", r5.getString("id"));
        jo.put("Issent",r5.getString("issent"));
        ja.put(jo);
}

   ret= final.put("List", ja).toString();
```

Try the above one. Should work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
 JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();


 JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

    try {
        Statement ac = DBL.getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet r5 = ac.executeQuery("Select * from msg");
        while(r5.next()){

            System.out.println("Value taken from database"+r5.getString("content"));
            JSONObject element = new JSONObject();

            element.put("Description", r5.getString("content"));
            element.put("Id", r5.getString("id"));
            element.put("Issent",r5.getString("issent"));
            ja.put(element);    
       }

       jo.put( "List", ja );
       System.out.println(jo.toString());
       ret= jo.toString();
```